# Wireshark LUA dissector - combine data from 2 UDP packets, display issue

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

I have a dissector which can read 2 udp packets and combine data from those.
Every time I select a packet (N) that is based on combining data from previous packet (N-1
) and current packet (N), I'm getting an error on the packet details on the custom protocol section.

Only when I select previous packet (N-1) and then the current packet (N), I can see the dissection as I expect and without any error.

Any idea how to solve the issue?

Comment: Hi mate, 
We're you able to solve your problem with the diameter lua dissector. I want to support/write my own diameter protocol in lua for all avps of diameter. Do you have any suggestions on how to get started with it?